# Applying Non-Numeric Data to Neural Nets

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'd like to include non-numeric data in my neural network. Specifically, I'm looking at GICS Industry Classifications (e.g., Utilities, Technology). I don't think this data can be meaningfully translated to numeric data.

One solution would be using a dummy variable to flag for each industry. The limitation of this approach would be the ballooning dimensions in the input layer of the neural net. Is there a more sophisticated approach to handling this type of problem?

Comment: You could dummy code and then apply some dimensionality reduction method (*e.g.* PCA)?

Comment: In this particular case, that may not work. Due to the nature of their business models, financial metrics should differ by industry. Removing the industry classification would create a lower tier bucket that comingles different industries where the flag was were deemed less sensitive (flags would be 0 on average), resulting in less predictive power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are totally right, strings or sequential numerical values `{'utilities': 0, 'technology': 1}` would not work in neural nets, because the network would learn to detect non-existent relations between the characters or numbers.

To avoid that we use something called [One Hot Encoding](https://machinelearningmastery.com/why-one-hot-encode-data-in-machine-learning/). It is a technique to encode each categorical variable as a state vector therefore removing the assumption that the categorical values have some sort of implied relations between them.

With an array `['Utilities', 'Technology']` your one hot encoding would look like:
`gics = [[1,0],[0,1]]`

Comment: Reading up more on this. Thanks.